# Where's the definitive list of "Stack Overflow spawn"?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I'm looking for the financial/money site based on SO software, but cannot for the life of me find it. Then I remembered there used to be a list of these sites somewhere. Where is the definitive list? I don't mean the one at the bottom of SO because that's a tight group focused on computers and not the entire picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new definitive list seems to be https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: The [old list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites/5#5) has a section named "Money". Most sites are still alive and "Basically Money" has been migrated to Stack Exchange 2.0.